# Can i directly connect this chip to PC and how can i amplify it (NRF24L01)?

Tags: rf, spi

Can i directly connect this chip to PC and how can i amplify it for increased range (NRF24L01)?

for more: http://www.semiconductorstore.com/cart/pc/viewPrd.asp?idproduct=765

Comment: The output power will be limited by the regulatory requirements of the 2.4GHz band .. what range did you have in mind?

Comment: If you have a 3V3 Compact 20-pin 4x4mm QFN slot in your PC, then yes.

Answer (score 3):

No, the IC cannot be directly connected to a PC, as it does not have any means of communicating with the PC through any of the standard interfaces the typical PC supports.

Please also note that the particular IC linked in the question is clearly indicated as obsolete on the [manufacturer's page](http://www.nordicsemi.com/eng/Products/2.4GHz-RF/nRF24L01):

> This product is **not recommended** for new designs. Nordic recommends its drop-in compatible nRF24L01+ or for a System-on-Chip solution the Nordic nRF24LE1 or nRF24LU1+.

The ***nRF24L01+*** or *nRF24L01Plus* is the direct replacement, which is also one of the recommended alternatives on the SemiconductorStore page link given in the question.

---

Also, the IC will in itself do very little for you: It needs to be used in a suitable circuit board, which will also need a whole bunch of other support components, to do anything meaningful at all.

The [datasheet for the nRF24L01+](http://www.nordicsemi.com/eng/nordic/download_resource/8041/1/29491346) provides sample schematics of how the IC can be used to implement a 24 GHz RF transceiver.

[image: Schematic]

Clearly, not a trivial matter of patching in some amplifier.

---

If the functionality of the nRF24L01+ is of interest, consider using a pre-built module such as [this one from eBay](http://www.ebay.com/itm/Arduino-NRF24L01-2-4GHz-Antenna-Wireless-Transceiver-Module-For-Microcontroll-/310670158878?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item4855626c1e) (*$1.42 including free international shipping*):

[image: nRF24L01+ module]

For connecting it to the PC you will **additionally require a suitable USB-connected microcontroller development board** such as an Arduino, or some suitable USB to TTL adapter.

---

***Edit:***

To get a slightly better understanding of how to use the Nordic IC, please read this article: "[Tutorial 0: Everything You Need to Know about 
the nRF24L01 ...](http://www.diyembedded.com/tutorials/nrf24l01_0/nrf24l01_tutorial_0.pdf)".

Comment: Thanks, and how much max distance of range?

Comment: @tango-tango That depends on what's between transmitter and receiver, also on relative humidity of the air, barometric pressure, and air ionization. The datasheet is also important to read and comprehend.

Answer (score 0):

Can you directly connect it? Obviously not. It doesn't have a USB, PCI, firewire, RS-232, or any other connector that would interface with anything on any normal PC. Can you build something to interface that IC and your PC? Yes, but it's a complex thing to do. The result will probably look something like this:

[image: PCI card]

To amplify it, you'd need an [RF amplifier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RF_power_amplifier) specified for use at 2.4GHz.

Comment: I think the quickest way would be to use a FTDI USB interface, and convert it into a USB wifi adapter. But then what's the point in buying a chip?

Comment: @phil do you have any good circuit RF amplifier for this chip?

Comment: My Macbook pro has a spi bus, i'm pretty sure with some modding and a driver i could connect it ;).